# Git: get commit diff without checking out code, is it possible?

Tags: git

I currently have the git url, 2 commit SHAs. Is it possible for me to get the commit diff between 2 SHAs without checking out the Git repo? Since the repo takes a lot of space and all I need is the commit difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GitHub, you can see it with this URL

https://github.com/xxx/yyy/compare/SHA_1...SHA_2

Comment: You have enlightened me to something I wish I had known before.